# Webpack and webpack dev server not serving static files

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

In the past I've been able to serve static files during development, but now I can't seem to do it anymore, given the latest verions of webpack and webpack-dev-server of `4.6.0` and `3.1.3`.

If I check my chrome inspector (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>) -> `Sources` tab and look under the `Network` tab and `localhost:8080`, I can only see two entries:

- (index)
- bundle.js

I should see my image files there that I'm trying to serve, but I don't. Its really frustrating when I see something like this in my console:

`Content not from webpack is served from C:\Users\PC-user\WebstormProjects\untitled/assets/`

But in reality, nothing is actually served. It feels rather betraying.

Anyway, these are my files:

**folder structure**

- assets
- node_modules
- src
- package.json
- package-lock.json
- webpack.config.js

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/index.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    // contentBase: './dist',
    contentBase: __dirname + "/assets/",
    hot: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Output Management'
    }),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/assets/",
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].js'
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your development server settings as below

```
  const path = require('path');
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    compress: true,
    open: true,
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    publicPath: '/',
  },
```

Comment: Rather than simply list a config a good StackOverflow answer should explain what that config actually does.

Answer (score 0):

Been having trouble with this too. But this helped.

```
devServer: {
        publicPath : '/public'
    }
```

worked for me. where the public is where my static files are.